# Ubuntu 16.04 empty purple screen after purging GUI interfaces

Tags: command-line, unity, grub2, plymouth

I installed Ubuntu Desktop 16.04 to raise a [FOG server](https://fogproject.org/). After that, with all needed installed, decided to turn it to "Server", better saying, I purged these packages:

- Unity;
- Plymouth

ubuntu-desktop was purged with Unity automatically.

But, when I boot this server, instead of that classical black server splash (grub menu), I see the blank purple screen. And it takes over 2 minutes to show user login prompt, unless I force it by typing <kbd>Ctrl</kbd><kbd>Alt</kbd><kbd>F1</kbd>

Do I have to change something in grub config file? Anything else to purge or to install? I don't wanna to reinstall it, because here at work [I cannot reach Ondrej repository, critical to reinstall FOG](https://forums.fogproject.org/topic/9770/diference-fog-storage-node/7?page=1).

Comment: did you remove "splash" from the grub command line?

Comment: No, I didn't because I would not to take a risk of grub damage. How will I do it?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

edit the file /etc/default/grub. change the following line to:

```
GRUB_CMDLINE_LINUX_DEFAULT="quiet"
```

You can even remove the "quiet" if you want a more verbose boot.
then run:

```
sudo update-grub
```